# In what scenarios is recommended a reliable session?

Tags: wcf, reliablesession

In few words, if I am not wrong, a session is used when I want to ensure that the packages are sent in order, and to be able to use sessions is needed a reliable connection.

But my doubt what kind of applications need that? In my case is a simple application in which a client request to a service data from a database, the service get the data from the database and send to the client the results. Also the client can requeset to add, modify or delete data from database. In this case, should I need a reliable connection and sessions or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session presumes that for some period of time you want to retain some data. Such a period of time, as far as session is concerned, refers to client's lifecycle that is when client opens up proxy, both service along with session are created, when client closes proxy service and session terminate their actions. There is exception when closing proxy does not actually perform it right away and this occures when you invoke one-way-operation. Service will keep working as long as operation performs its action despite the fact that it previously received an order to get rid of instance. 
Based on provided information I assume the best choice would be PerCall. You do not store any data between calls and every single call can be perceived separately. Additionaly, leverage of ConcurrencyMode set to multiple so as to allow services being created simultaneously.
Personally, I find session useful in MSMQ, whenever I want to specific number of messages be wrapped into single queue-message. If error occures, regardless of whether which message is in charge of it, the whole queue-message is rolled back.